# Youtube iframe embed in wordpress: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube, youtube-api, custom-wordpress-pages

I've encountered issue with embedding youtube on wordpress project I'm working on. Previously I've used simmilar code on one of my projects with success and no errors, but it wasn't wordpress. 
My problem is that both direct embedding using `<iframe>` and utilizing youtube API yields an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null
at YouTubeDelegate.self.unregister_element (<anonymous>:194:36)
at remove_element (<anonymous>:406:43)
at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:428:21)
```

My simplest iframe embed code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-Pau48X5TlU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Things I've also tried so far:

- disabling all custom js
- disabling all styles
- changing iframe embed to youtube JS API
- embedding iframe on various pages and template parts
- deploying site to server instead of localhost
- stripping embed code from all attributes except src
- changing src to http / https
- debugging it via console is nearly impossible as error is inside API fetched after each refresh, so it requires clicking through ~500 steps...

And I've run out of ideas.
You can head to http://adyry.com/dhw/ to see the error, I've embedded random video in header.

**My guess is that it is somehow related to wordpress engine, which forces embedding via oEmbed?**

I hope you can help me, Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, for future reference, it was a bug caused by "Disable HTML5 Autoplay" addon in chrome, I've created issue on their github.